# How to validate if element is enabled/disabled dynamically in robot-framework and store it's result in a variable?

Tags: robotframework

I am still learning robot-framework, I have done lot of research on the internet but could not get a clue, can anyone please help here.
In a web page automation testing I need to validated if an element is enabled before I do any other operation on it.
for example a drop-down menu, I need to check if that drop-down menu is enabled or say clickable or not before I select any option from it.

tried all possible ways to achieve this but could not get any progress, did lot of research on internet as well.

```
Run Keyword If    "Element is enabled"    "Select an option"    Else No Operation
```

I should be able to identify if the element which I am trying to select is enabled or not to proceed ahead.

Answer (score 6):

You can try it as below

```
${Status}=     Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should be Enabled    id=dropdown
Run Keyword If    '${Status}'=='True'      Click Element    id=dropdown
```

First line will get you the status of the element whether it is enabled or not.Based on the return value (True / False ), you can perform any option ("Select an option")